# flutter build runner showing error and cannot generate files

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, flutter-dependencies, angular-dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkde4.png)

part 'data_model.g.dart'; target  hasn't been generated

I have tried so many ways to fix it but it does not work anyone can give a answer to solve it.

I tried updating dependencies and so many command lines

'flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --use-polling-watcher --delete-conflicting-outputs'

If anyone could fix it.

Comment: check your student model file's name is `data_model.dart`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add hive_generator at the dev_dependencies. Here's the link; https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator